# equation has bad pdf out put in Latex

Tags: formatting

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l}
{s_{\max }}\\ =  - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\alpha  {{p_i}_j\ln {p_i}_j} \\
 =  - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \sum\limits_{j = 0}^\alpha  {{p_i}{}_j\ln \left[ {{a_i}\exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i})j)} \right]} \\
 =  - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left[ {\sum {{p_i}_j\ln {a_i}}  - \mu \sum {j{p_i}_j - \nu \sum j } {\varepsilon _i}{p_i}_j} \right]\\
 =  - \sum {{q_i}\ln {a_i}}  + \mu a + \nu b\\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \ln \left[ {\exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}) + 1)} \right] + \sum {\left( {\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}} \right)} {a_i}\sum {j{p_i}_j} \\
 = \sum {{q_i}} \ln \left[ {1 + \exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}))} \right] + \left( {\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}} \right)\overline {{n_i}} \\
 = \sum {{q_i}\left\{ {\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{\overline {{n_i}} }}{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }}} \right) + \overline {{n_i}} \ln \left( {\frac{1}{{\overline {{n_i}} }} - 1} \right)} \right\}} \\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left\{ {\ln \frac{1}{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }} + \overline {{n_i}} \ln \left( {\frac{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }}{{\overline {{n_i}} }}} \right)} \right\}\\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}\left\{ { - \ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} ) + \overline {{n_i}} \ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} ) - \overline {{n_i}} \ln \overline {{n_i}} } \right\}} \\
 = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left\{ { - \overline {{n_i}} \ln \overline {{n_i}}  - (1 - \overline {{n_i}} )\ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} )} \right\}
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

above equation giving bad looking pdf why?

Comment: you have not told us the `\documentclass`  so we can not run that example to see what is wrong, but fairly clearly it is not an array (that is, a matrix of values) but a list of equations which should be aligned on = so you should be using `align` from `amsmath`

Comment: (you should not need `\limits` after every `\sum`)

Comment: Respected Sir I was using a  \documentclass[12pt]{article} and more over the above expression is an output of mathtype equation converter from word to latex.

Comment: Hmmm the conversion could be better:-)

Comment: Sir, I will be in touch with you, thanx again.

Comment: You have a lot of expressions of the form `{p_i}_j`. Is this correct, or should it be `p_{ij}`? I.e., is `j` a subscript to the variable `p_i`, or are `i` and `j` both subscripts to the variable `p`?

Answer (score 4):

`array` is designed for matrices (arrays) of values, not displayed equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
s_{\max } 
 &=  - \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \sum_{j = 0}^\alpha  {{p_i}_j\ln {p_i}_j} \\
 &=  - \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \sum_{j = 0}^\alpha  {{p_i}{}_j\ln \left[ {{a_i}\exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i})j)} \right]} \\
 &=  - \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left[ {\sum {{p_i}_j\ln {a_i}}  - \mu \sum {j{p_i}_j - \nu \sum j } {\varepsilon _i}{p_i}_j} \right]\\
 &=  - \sum {{q_i}\ln {a_i}}  + \mu a + \nu b\\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \ln \left[ {\exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}) + 1)} \right] + \sum {\left( {\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}} \right)} {a_i}\sum {j{p_i}_j} \\
 &= \sum {{q_i}} \ln \left[ {1 + \exp ( - (\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}))} \right] + \left( {\mu  + \nu {\varepsilon _i}} \right)\overline {{n_i}} \\
 &= \sum {{q_i}\left\{ {\ln \left( {1 + \frac{{\overline {{n_i}} }}{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }}} \right) + \overline {{n_i}} \ln \left( {\frac{1}{{\overline {{n_i}} }} - 1} \right)} \right\}} \\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left\{ {\ln \frac{1}{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }} + \overline {{n_i}} \ln \left( {\frac{{1 - \overline {{n_i}} }}{{\overline {{n_i}} }}} \right)} \right\}\\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}\left\{ { - \ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} ) + \overline {{n_i}} \ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} ) - \overline {{n_i}} \ln \overline {{n_i}} } \right\}} \\
 &= \sum_{i = 1}^n {{q_i}} \left\{ { - \overline {{n_i}} \ln \overline {{n_i}}  - (1 - \overline {{n_i}} )\ln (1 - \overline {{n_i}} )} \right\}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, since I am new to latex  I am surprised  how stackExchange can be so helpful.

Comment: Respected Sir David, I had a long equation to write and used your solution to great effect,